# Oracle TO_DATE not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query which is not returning any rows. But there are records which are greater than 25-JUN-90 date. Why is it not working?

```
{SELECT employee_id, last_name,hire_date
   FROM employees WHERE hire_date > TO_DATE('25-JUN-90','dd-mon-yy');}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use the RR date format mask to change 90 to 1990:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name,hire_date
FROM employees WHERE hire_date > TO_DATE('25-JUN-90','dd-mon-RR');
```

Answer (score 2):

Which century does it translate '90' to?  1990 or 2090?

See [Oracle Dates and Times](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html) for one description of Oracle date format characters.  As [Jeffrey Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103295/jeffrey-kemp)'s answer suggests, for the time being (the next 30 years or so), you can get '1990' from '90' using the format letters 'RR'.  However, it would be better to use 4-digit years; the lessons of Y2K have been forgotten already, it seems.

Comment: I got what you mean, what I need in 1990 but I get the user input like 90, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: @need_the_buzz: looking at Jeffrey Kemp's answer, it appears that you need to use 'RR' - and you should give him an up vote if you've not already done so.