# Oracle date comparison using to_date not working

Tags: oracle, date

I am using Oracle XE on my machine.
Defined a table as :

```
Name       Type
ENAME      VARCHAR2(20) 
DOJ        DATE
```

Firing a simple select:

> select * from test1.tasty1;

```
ENAME                DOJ
sat                  08-DEC-16
```

So ok - I am aware that DATE field has time component in it.
The following query using TRUNC works fine:

> select * from test1.tasty1 where trunc(DOJ) = '08-DEC-16';

Now I wanted to test the 'to_date' function - but none of the below queries worked - wonder why ?

> select * from test1.tasty1 where DOJ =
>   to_date('08-12-2016','DD-MM-YYYY');
>   select * from test1.tasty1 where
>   DOJ = to_date('08-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY');
>   select * from
>   test1.tasty1 where DOJ = to_date('08-DEC-16','DD-MON-YY');
>   select
>   * from test1.tasty1 where DOJ = to_date('08-DEC-16','dd-mon-RR');

Had taken a look at the following on SO:
[Oracle TO_DATE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762346/oracle-to-date-not-working)

so not sure what is wrong here ?

Comment: Please try the following query: `SELECT * FROM test1.tasty1 WHERE DOJ = '2016-08-12'` ... does this return anything?  AFAIK some of the 4 queries you tried should be returning that record.

Comment: the above fails with 'literal does not match format string'  if I try 'select * from test1.tasty1 where DOJ = '08-DEC-16';' gives no results

Comment: This is not what I asked you to run.  I asked you to run `WHERE DOJ = '2016-08-12'`

Comment: well if you read my response- I did respond that it fails with 'literal does not match format string'

Comment: Are you certain that `DOJ` is a `date` column?  This is very strange behavior I am seeing here.

Comment: yes it is - inserted value as sysdate - would that cause any issues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question and comments, it appears that this is the sequence of events which happened.

You did the following `INSERT` into your table:

```
INSERT INTO test1.tasty1 VALUES ('sat', SYSDATE)
```

Keep in mind that dates in Oracle have both a date *and* a time component.  So even though you did insert the date `'2016-12-08'` you *also* inserted a time component.  As a result, the following query is not returning any records:

```
SELECT * FROM test1.tasty1 WHERE DOJ = '2016-08-12'
```

This is probably because you never specified the time component, and therefore the record you inserted earlier is not matching.  If you want to compare only the date portion, you can use `TRUNC` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM test1.tasty1 WHERE TRUNC(DOJ) = '2016-08-12'
```

The solution to your problem moving forward would be to wrap `SYSDATE` with `TRUNC` during the insert, if you really only want to deal with the date components.

By the way, the format `'08-DEC-16'` used as a literal will not be recognized by Oracle as a valid date.  Instead, use `'2016-12-08'`.

Comment: Tim - thanks - I get the time part and the need to use TRUNC. This is understood. What I am not understanding is - does this mean that TO_DATE will not work if there is a time component involved ( which it is in my example ) ?

Comment: @satishmarathe In your case, the column against which you are making the comparison _does_ have a time component, so if you don't also match for that then yes the comparison won't work AFAIK.  But if you are comparing a truncated date with no time component against `to_date` also created with no time component, then I would expect the comparison to work.

Comment: ok so now it makes sense - the to_date will also take into consideration the 'time' aspect and since we are doing a comparison ( not greater than or less than ) - it tries to do an exact match - this raises another question - if I just simply want to use a Date field and am not interested in time - what data type should I use - will read up and if needed - post a separate question - thanks for your input

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried like this as comparison of date with date is correct:

```
select * from test1.tasty1 where to_date(DOJ,'DD-MM-YYYY') = to_date('08-12-2016','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Compare apples with apples and not with mangoes.

Comment: Oracle advises against passing a Date object to the to_date which you are recommending on the LHS and FYI - your suggested SQL also gives no results - the apples to apples comparison returned oranges !!! :). which is making sense based on what @TimBiegeleisen states - there is a time component involved here

Answer (score 1):

What it worked from is instead of make a date to compare, change the date column to char with `to_char(datecol, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '01-01-2022'`